Address of local variable gives invalid address
I'm running into a bug in my code where the address of a local stack variable
is invalid. I've been trying to debug this with lldb.
In the lldb prompt below, you can see that &dominance_frontier gives the address
0x0000000000000001 which then causes a SIGSEGV on hash_table_init call line 121.
However &dominator_tree_adj, gives a valid address. I'm completely baffled as to
why this might be the case.
Process 70998 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step over
    frame #0: 0x0000000100006fd0 ir`ComputeDominanceFrontier(function=0x00006000030f8000) at dominators.c:121:9
   111          struct Array postorder_traversal = postorder (function->entry_basic_block);
   112          struct DFAConfiguration config = DominatorDFAConfiguration (function);
   113          struct DFAResult result = run_DFA (&config, function);
   114  
   115          HashTable dominator_tree_adj = ComputeDominatorTree (function, &result);
   116          printf("%p\n", &dominator_tree_adj);
   117          HashTable dominance_frontier;
   118          printf("%ld\n", sizeof(dominance_frontier));
   119  
   120  
-> 121          hash_table_init (&dominance_frontier);
   122          // Compute the transpose graph from the dominator tree adjacency list
   123          // Each node is guaranteed to have only one direct predecessor, since
   124          // each node can only have one immediate dominator. We will need this
   125          // in the DF algorithm below
   126          HashTable dominator_tree_transpose;
   127          hash_table_init (&dominator_tree_transpose);
   128  
   129          struct HashTableEntry *entry;
   130          size_t entry_iter = 0;
   131  
Target 0: (ir) stopped.
(lldb) p &dominance_frontier
(HashTable *) 0x0000000000000001
(lldb) p &dominator_tree_adj
(HashTable *) 0x000000016fdfef38

I've been compiling my code with make DEBUG=yes
OPT = -O3
FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra
CC = cc
OBJECTS =   ir_parser.o \
            main.o \
            threeaddr_parser.o \
            instruction.o \
            function.o \
            basicblock.o \
            constant.o \
            utils.o \
            value.o \
            array.o \
            mem.o \
            map.o \
            dfa.o \
            dominators.o


ifdef DEBUG
    OPT = -g
else
    OPT = -O3
endif


all: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OPT) $(FLAGS) $^ -o ir

%.o: %.c *.h
    $(CC) $(OPT) $(FLAGS) -c $< -o $@


clean:
    rm *.o

This is the location of the segfault:
Process 10619 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x9)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100005060 ir`_hash_table_init(table=0x0000000000000001, size=10) at map.c:21:21
   11   // Open addressing, linear probe hash table.
   12   
   13   unsigned long uint64_t_hash_function (uint64_t key)
   14   {
   15           // Simple hash function for demonstration
   16           return key;
   17   }
   18   
   19   void _hash_table_init (HashTable *table, size_t size)
   20   {
-> 21           table->size = size;
   22           table->count = 0;
   23           table->buckets = ir_calloc (table->size, sizeof (HashTableEntry));
   24   }
   25   void hash_table_init (HashTable *table)
   26   {
   27           _hash_table_init (table, MAP_INIT_SIZE_CNT);
   28   }
   29   
   30   // Create a new hash table
   31   HashTable *hash_table_create (size_t size)
Target 0: (ir) stopped.

Input file:
fn test4(%1, %2) {

    alloca %9, 5
    add %3, %1, %2 
    store %9, %3
    cmp %4, %1, %2 
    jumpif 1, %4


    sub %5, %3, 1  
    jumpif 2, %5   

1:
    add %6, %1, 20 
    jump 3    


2:
    add %7, %2, 30 

    
3:
    sub %8, %3, %3 
}

./ir -f path/to/input/file

I'm using Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)
Full code is here: https://github.com/CoconutJJ/compiler-optimization/blob/d3244e8c9f96e8180c924533abf8f5daac15238c/ir/dominators.c#L115

Please post a [mre] here, not a link to a remote site.

Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

If you put the breakpoint inside hash_table_init, do you see the same value?  Where does the segfault actually occur (your lldb output seems to be stopped due to single-stepping, not at the actual SIGSEGV site)?  Do you observe the same behavior with gdb instead?  What compiler version and architecture is this?

@NateEldredge I've edited the question to include compiler version. I'm on Apple Silicon M1. I do see the same value in hash_table_init. Running this is a ubuntu docker container and using gdb instead, it shows the segfault on the function return line instead in ComputeDominanceFrontier .

Have you looked at the disassembly of the function in question?  If it really is deliberately passing 1 instead of a valid stack address, which would be a compiler bug, then the asm of that function should be obviously wrong.

We'd also need the input file.

@dbush Running this with valgrind inside a Ubuntu docker container with valgrind --leak-check=yes gives a "Invalid write of size 8". But this doesn't seem very helpful since it is just referring to the invalid address which I already know

@NateEldredge I've edited the question to include the input file and run command

@NateEldredge I'll try looking at the assembly, although I'm not very adept at reading ARM assembly code.

@Barmar I'm not sure how much smaller you would like this example. I could provide a simple C program that also segfaults, but then it would not help my issue as I would know what was wrong already. All the files I linked in the github link are required to compile my code. Please let me know if you have suggestions on how I could improve the question.

The idea is that, as much as possible, you create a small standalone program that only calls this function, with everything else removed or stubbed out.

Ah, I see it.  dominators.h declares ComputeDominanceFrontier as returning void, and that's the declaration seen by the caller, but it actually returns HashTable.  I'll write an answer explaining how this causes what you see.

Or I guess not, since it's been closed.  But: when a function returns a sufficiently large struct, the caller is meant to allocate space for the return value and pass a pointer to it (in x8 for aarch64).  Since the compiler sees that dominance_frontier will be used as the return value, it optimizes away its stack space (even at -O0) and uses the passed pointer from x8 as its address instead.  Here, since main thought the function returned void, register x8 just contains garbage instead.

If you had included dominators.h into dominators.c as you always should, the compiler would have caught this.

@NateEldredge THANKS SO MUCH! That was the problem! I can't believe I didn't see that. I have voted to reopen the question. I'll accept your answer.

dominators.c
HashTable ComputeDominanceFrontier (struct Function *function)
^^^^^^^^^

dominators.h
void ComputeDominanceFrontier (struct Function *function);
^^^^

Oopsie.
The function ComputeDominanceFrontier is called from main.c which includes dominators.h, so the caller thinks that it returns void.  But according to the definition in dominators.c, it actually returns HashTable.  This mismatch is the cause of the crash, as explained below.
The compiler does not catch this because you did not include dominators.h into dominators.c, so when compiling dominators.c, it had no idea that some other source file was seeing a conflicting declaration.  For this reason, when a header declares a global function, you should always make sure that header is included into the source file that defines the function.  You can help enforce this with -Wmissing-prototypes, which gives a warning whenever a global function is defined without having previously been declared.  See Compiler warning for function defined without prototype in scope?

What happens is this: on arm64, like many other platforms, when a function returns a struct type that can't be returned in a register, it's returned by "hidden reference": the caller allocates space for the return value, and passes an extra hidden argument with the address of that space.  On arm64 the extra argument is passed in register x8.  Then the called function is responsible for copying its return value into that space.
In this case, since main didn't know that ComputeDominanceFrontier was returning a struct type, it didn't allocate such space, and left x8 containing garbage (in your case, its value happened to be 1).
If compiled naively, you would then expect to see a crash at the end of the function, when dominance_frontier is copied from the stack into the bogus return value address.  And it sounds like that's what you did see in your Ubuntu test (which, let me guess, used gcc instead of clang?).
However, the compiler can optimize this: instead of using stack space for dominance_frontier, use the return value space allocated by the caller.  Then we don't need to copy that data before returning, because it was populated "in place".  It appears that clang performs this optimization even when optimizations are "off".  So as such, dominance_frontier doesn't really live on ComputeDominanceFrontier's stack frame, and &dominance_frontier isn't a stack address but rather the return value address passed by the caller - which in this case is garbage.

Thanks again! I'll add the -Wmissing-prototypes to my makefile

@thebusybee: OP already had -Wall -Wextra.  They don't include -Wmissing-prototypes because there's nothing inherently wrong about not declaring a function before defining it, and in a small program (e.g. single source file) it would be pointless and annoying to do so.

From the code you post (no code but the debugger screenshots) it can be inferred that you use:
I'm running into a bug in my code where the address of a local stack variable is invalid. I've been trying to debug this with lldb.

In the lldb prompt below, you can see that &dominance_frontier gives the address 0x0000000000000001 which then causes a SIGSEGV on hash_table_init call line 121. However &dominator_tree_adj, gives a valid address. I'm completely baffled as to why this might be the case.

Process 70998 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step over
    frame #0: 0x0000000100006fd0 ir`ComputeDominanceFrontier(function=0x00006000030f8000) at dominators.c:121:9
   111          struct Array postorder_traversal = postorder (function->entry_basic_block);
   112          struct DFAConfiguration config = DominatorDFAConfiguration (function);
   113          struct DFAResult result = run_DFA (&config, function);
   114  
   115          HashTable dominator_tree_adj = ComputeDominatorTree (function, &result);
   116          printf("%p\n", &dominator_tree_adj);
   117          HashTable dominance_frontier;
   118          printf("%ld\n", sizeof(dominance_frontier));
   119  
   120  
-> 121          hash_table_init (&dominance_frontier);
   122          // Compute the transpose graph from the dominator tree adjacency list
   123          // Each node is guaranteed to have only one direct predecessor, since
   124          // each node can only have one immediate dominator. We will need this
   125          // in the DF algorithm below
   126          HashTable dominator_tree_transpose;
   127          hash_table_init (&dominator_tree_transpose);
   128  
   129          struct HashTableEntry *entry;
   130      

in line 117 you have
HashTable dominance_frontier;

this is a variable representing the structure of a HashTable that you never initialize.  All the other routines require the pointer to the HashTable variable that have not been initialized.   I don't know why you don't initialize the structure, but passing the address will be of little or no help because all those functions seem to require you to call hash_table_create to create the proper structure contents initially.
Probably your code should have been
    HashTable *dominator_tree_transpose = hash_table_create(number_of_hash_entries);
    hash_table_init(dominator_tree_transpose);

but as you provide no source code, I cannot further guess.  I don't believe you are free to call hash_table_init() passing it the address of an OBJECT.  But I can be wrong.  Next time post the source code... not a debug session.  Include the full definition of HashTable type, hash_table_create() and hash_table_init() functions, because the use of both functions cannot be inferred from the posted code.
Note: I post this as an answer because that seems to be the cause of failure.  But it is not clear enough from the snippets shown.

Ideally it would have been within the question, but OP did link the full code, and hash_table_init is fine; it does the initialization. https://github.com/CoconutJJ/compiler-optimization/blob/d3244e8c9f96e8180c924533abf8f5daac15238c/ir/map.c#L19

Well I saw it later, but that example does not meet the requirements of SO about minimality and reproduzability.  Having to build a full application is not the way of showing things.  Instead of voting to close the question, I preferred to answer based on what whas written and not to dig in a whole multiproject git repository.
